# Pandas_Pivot table - making additional columns from division of merged columns

Tags: python, pandas, pivot, pivot-table, subset

I'm trying to run the following function

```
def make_europe_view(data):

    data['% Rev'] = data.GrossRevenue_GBP/data.GrossRevenue_GBP.sum()

    tmean = lambda x :stats.trim_mean(x, 0.1)

    pivot = pd.pivot_table(data[(data['New_category_ID'] != 0)&(data['YYYY'] == 2016)], 
                                index = 'New_category',  
                                values=['GrossRevenue_GBP','MOVC_GBP','PM_GBP', '% Rev'],
                                aggfunc= {'MOVC_GBP':tmean,'PM_GBP':tmean,'GrossRevenue_GBP':[np.sum,tmean],'% Rev':np.sum })



    pivot['% PM'] = pivot['PM_GBP']/pivot[('GrossRevenue_GBP')]['<lambda>']
    #pivot['% MOVC'] = pivot['MOVC_GBP']/Tmean_GR
    pivot['Country'] = 'EU'
    pivot['product_cat'] = pivot.index

    #pivot = pivot[['product_cat', '% Rev', 'GrossRevenue_GBP', 'MOVC_GBP', 'PM_GBP', '% PM', '% MOVC', 'Country']]

    return pivot
```

I want to aggregate Gross Revenue by truncated mean and sum, I have no issue generating the pivot table however I am experiencing issues when it comes to create some additional columns. Specifically this part of the code:

```
 pivot['% PM'] = pivot['PM_GBP']/pivot[('GrossRevenue_GBP')]['<lambda>']
```

I am trying to create a column that will calculated % truncated mean of PM by taking the truncated mean of 'PM_GBP' column as a percentage of the truncated mean of 'GrossRevenue_GBP' column

It generates the following error:

```
ValueError: Wrong number of items passed 25, placement implies 1
```

[image: output of pivot:]

Would really appreciate some help with this.

column names for pivot when I run `list()`:

```
[('GrossRevenue_GBP', '<lambda>'),  ('GrossRevenue_GBP', 'sum'),  ('% Rev', 'sum'),  ('MOVC_GBP', '<lambda>'),  ('PM_GBP', '<lambda>'),  ('Country', ''),  ('product_cat', '')]
```

Comment: What are sample data (`pivot`) after `pd.pivot_table(...)` ?

Comment: @jezrael - I have added in above, output when written into excel file for pivot

Comment: (numbers have been sanitised)

Comment: Sorry, now i have time for answer. Please check it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use tuples for select values in `MultiIndex` in columns:

```
tups = [('GrossRevenue_GBP', '<lambda>'),  ('GrossRevenue_GBP', 'sum'),  ('% Rev', 'sum'),  ('MOVC_GBP', '<lambda>'),  ('PM_GBP', '<lambda>'),  ('Country', ''),  ('product_cat', '')]
idx = list('ab')
cols = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(tups)
pivot = pd.DataFrame([[7,4,5,8,4,5,1],
                   [1,5,7,3,9,6,7]], columns=cols, index=idx)
print (pivot)
  GrossRevenue_GBP     % Rev MOVC_GBP   PM_GBP Country product_cat
          <lambda> sum   sum <lambda> <lambda>                    
a                7   4     5        8        4       5           1
b                1   5     7        3        9       6           7
```

---

```
pivot['% PM'] = pivot[('PM_GBP','<lambda>')]/pivot[('GrossRevenue_GBP','<lambda>')]
print (pivot)
  GrossRevenue_GBP     % Rev MOVC_GBP   PM_GBP Country product_cat      % PM
          <lambda> sum   sum <lambda> <lambda>                              
a                7   4     5        8        4       5           1  0.571429
b                1   5     7        3        9       6           7  9.000000
```

For simplier life is possible remove `MultiIndex` and create columns:

```
#rename columns by dict
pivot = pivot.rename(columns={'<lambda>':'tmean'})
#remove multiindex
pivot.columns = pivot.columns.map('_'.join).str.strip('_')

#simply divide
pivot['% PM'] = pivot['PM_GBP_tmean']/pivot['GrossRevenue_GBP_tmean']
print (pivot)
   GrossRevenue_GBP_tmean  GrossRevenue_GBP_sum  % Rev_sum  MOVC_GBP_tmean  \
a                       7                     4          5               8   
b                       1                     5          7               3   

   PM_GBP_tmean  Country  product_cat      % PM  
a             4        5            1  0.571429  
b             9        6            7  9.000000
```

Comment: this is a much more elegant way of doing it, really appreciate your help with this!

Comment: Glad can help! Nice weekend!

Comment: Strange.. on running the code I am getting the following error: AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'str'

Comment: Maybe some older pandas version. What is `print (pd.show_versions())` ?

Comment: last is `0.20.3`

Comment: I had an out of date version, was running 0.18.x, I have updated. however now I get the error `KeyError: 'PM_GBP'`

Comment: It means you want select column which not exist. Check columns names by `print (df.columns.tolist())`

Comment: I have figured out the issue - I had to move a piece of code before map and this has fixed it. Thank you for your patience

Comment: No problem, I know and I am online I try answer  on comment